# Getting the value of a declared variable in a method to be passed to Aspect

Tags: java, spring-aop

Hi I am quite new to AOP so I am trying to know if its possible to get the value of a variable and be passed to the Aspect here is what I have done so far.

this is the method where I want to get the value of the variable from

```
public Object someMethod(String id
                         String address;
                         String name
                        ) {

 //I want to get the value of this variable
 Optional<String> currentId = id.isPresent() ? id : someOtherMethod(address);

 return new Object();

}
```

and this is my Aspect

```
@Around("@annotation("Audit")")
public Object auditLog(JointPoint jointPoint) throws Throwable {
    //Do something here with the varible declared in someMethod
}
```

thank you

Comment: Inside Aspect method you can get method argument or method result.

Comment: The whole point of a **local** variable is its locality. This is a Java concept (also found in many other languages), and there is nothing you can do in an aspect to change the whole Java language semantics.